# Can I easily port a Rails API to use GrahQL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, graphql

I'm building a project where there's an already implemented REST API running in Rails but we want to start using GraphQL. I'm using the 'graphql' gem but everywhere I look seems to imply that I should implement everything all over again in GraphQL, is that so or is there a way to tell GraphQL to use the Rails controllers?

I have queries working but by implementing them straight in GraphQL, I have looked a lot of places but some of the workarounds don't seem to work.

For example:

```rb
module Types
  class QueryType < Types::BaseObject
    include GraphQL::Types::Relay::HasNodeField
    include GraphQL::Types::Relay::HasNodesField

    # Add root-level fields here.
    # They will be entry points for queries on your schema.
    field :users, [Types::UserType]

    def users
      User.all
    end

  end
end
```

Is there a way to use something like users#index for example?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Your question will likely be downvoted and eventually closed.  You'll need to provide better detail and code examples to keep that from happening.

Comment: A RESTful API and GraphQL are indeed based on very different concepts, ideas, and design patterns. GraphQL cannot simply reuse existing REST controllers. You will need to implement everything all over again in GraphQL.